# Display message if there are no applications available

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display a message that says "No Notifications Available".  I want this to be displayed if no apps are contained on the page.  So if the page is black then the message should be displayed.  I currently have the message set up in the HTML, but it just isn't displaying properly.

Controller

```
$scope.dismissNotifications = function(app, ev) {
  var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
    .title('Confirm Dismiss All')
    .content('Are you sure you want to dismiss notifications?')
    .ariaLabel('Confirm Dismiss All')
    .ok('Confirm')
    .cancel('Cancel')
    .targetEvent(ev);

  $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
    var notifications = app.notifications;
    for (var id in notifications) {
      Service.dismissNotification(notifications[id].id).then(function(notificationId) {
        return function (response) {
          delete app.notifications[notificationId];
        }
      });
    }
  }, function() {
    return false;
  });
};

$scope.init = function () {
  Service.getUserAppsByEmail(SecService.secState.username).then(function (response) {
    var apps = response.applications;
    $scope.appList['alerts'] = {
      name: 'Alerts',
      notifications: {}
    } ;
    for(var i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
      $scope.appList[apps[i].appId] = {
        name: apps[i].name,
        icon: apps[i].icon,
        notifications: {}
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
<md-content flex="100">
<div class="m2" style="color: #FFFFFF; padding: 24px 36px;" ng-if="!(appList | NotificationsExistFilter)">No Notifications Available</div>
  <div ng-repeat="app in appList" ng-show="(app.notifications | AssociativeArrayFilter) > 0">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" style="background-color: #3F454b; padding: 8px 16px;">
        <img ng-src="{{app.icon}}" style="width: 36px;" ng-show="app.icon">
        <md-icon style="width: 36px; height: 36px; color: #FFFFFF;" md-svg-icon="images/icons/error.svg" ng-hide="app.icon"></md-icon>

        <p class="m2" style="color: #FFFFFF; margin-left: 16px;">{{app.name}}</p>

        <div flex></div>

        <md-icon class="rotate-clockwise-45 no-outline" style="color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;" md-svg-icon="images/icons/add_circle.svg" ng-click="dismissNotifications(app, $event)"></md-icon>
      </div>

      <div class="nots" ng-repeat="notification in app.notifications | orderObjectBy: 'unixEpoch' : true" layout="row" layout-align="start center" style="padding: 8px 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);">

        <p flex class="m2" style="color: #FFFFFF; margin-left: 16px;">{{notification.message}} - <span class="m3"; style="color: #FFFFFF"; style="opacity: .3;"; am-time-ago="notification.whenCreated"></span></p>

        <md-icon style="color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;" class="no-outline" md-svg-icon="images/icons/close.svg" ng-click="dismissNotification(notification)"></md-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Try to shorten the code and isolate the problem, there is too much going on here.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: Moderators notified of multiple instances of question vandalism.

Comment: I was adding some quality information to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix what I was trying to accomplish.  Adding a filter is the easiest fix in this case.

Add this in the HTML

```
<div class="m2" style="color: #FFFFFF; padding: 24px 36px;" ng-if="!(appList | NotificationsExistFilter)">No Notifications or Alerts Available</div>
```

Add this filter in the Controller

```
angular.module('notifications').filter('NotificationsExistFilter', function () {
return function (apps) {
if (!apps) {
  return false;
}

var retVal = false;
angular.forEach(apps, function (app, index) {
  if (!retVal) {
    angular.forEach(app.notifications, function (value, index) {
      if (!retVal) {
        retVal = true;
      }
    })
  }
});

return retVal;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ng-hide tag into your script to push a div to run.
Here's an example with

http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/k4u5z/

In`<p ng-hide="filteredBars.length">Nothing here!</p>`  the boolean hide true/false is set by the number of items in the list.  in your case, if you add this `<p>` in your html (or another div or whatever you want), and set `ng-hide="appList.length"`, you will get the result you want.

Comment: This didn't work for me either.  I added some code to use a filter, but now the message is displayed always no matter what.  I think there is something wrong with the new filter I am using.

Answer (score 0):

//In your html outside of ng-repeat

```
<div ng-show = "appListEmpty" class="m2" style="color: #FFFFFF; padding: 24px 36px;"  (INCLUDE A FILTER OR SORTS HERE)>No Notifications or Alerts Available<div>
```

//in your controller(place if statement inside of your init function)

```
$scope.appListEmpty = false;
if(appList.length < 1){
$scope.appListEmpty = true;
```

}